# Potential energy of phonons as harmonic oscillators

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, phonons

I'm trying to derive the phonon hamiltonian which is anologous to a collection
of independent harmonic oscillators. I've already have kinetic energy but I'm kinda stuck on the potential energy. The initial expression I have is $$V=\sum_{\boldsymbol{R},\boldsymbol{R'}}\sum_{a,b}\sum_{\mu,\nu}D_{a\mu,b\nu}(\boldsymbol{R},\boldsymbol{R'})u_{a\mu}(\boldsymbol{R})u_{b\nu}(\boldsymbol{R'})$$

where $$D_{a\mu,b\nu}(\boldsymbol{R},\boldsymbol{R'})$$ is dynamical matrix and $$u_{a\mu}(\boldsymbol{R})=\sum\limits_{\boldsymbol{q}\lambda}\frac{1}{\sqrt N}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^\lambda(\boldsymbol{q})e^{i\boldsymbol{q}\cdot(\boldsymbol{R}+\boldsymbol{r}_a)}Q_\lambda(\boldsymbol{q})$$ is the displacement.

I think I should use the following identities (possibly in this order ?) to get to the final expression
$$\omega^2\varepsilon_{a\mu}^\lambda(\boldsymbol{q})=\sum_{b,\nu}D_{a\mu,b\nu}\,\varepsilon_{a\mu}^\lambda(\boldsymbol{q})$$

$$\sum_\boldsymbol{R}e^{i\boldsymbol{q}\cdot\boldsymbol{R}}=N\delta_{\boldsymbol{q},0}$$

$$e^{\lambda}_{a\mu}(\boldsymbol{q})=\left[e^{\lambda}_{a\mu}(\boldsymbol{-q})\right]^*$$

$$\sum_{a,\mu}e^{\lambda}_{a\mu}(\boldsymbol{q})e^{\lambda'}_{a\mu}(\boldsymbol{q})=\delta_{\lambda\lambda'}$$

$$Q_{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{q})=\left[Q_{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{-q})\right]^*$$

The result should be $$V=\sum_{\boldsymbol{q},\lambda}\omega(\boldsymbol{q})|Q_\lambda(\boldsymbol{q})|^2$$
I'm just not getting anywhere with those sums. I'm not able to arrive at anything meaningful. Can anyone help me with this derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R,a,\mu$ denote, respectively, the coordinates of the $R$th unit cell, the location of the $a$th basis atom, and the direction along the $\mu$th primitive vector. The potential energy within the harmonic approximation is

$
V=\frac12\sum_{Ra\mu}\sum_{R'b\nu}\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(R,R')\,u_{a\mu}(R)\,u_{b\nu}(R')
$

where $u_{a\mu}(R)$ are the thermal displacements away from equilibrium (with the time dependence suppressed) and $\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(R,R')$ are elements of the force constant matrix. In general, these are not the same as the elements of the dynamical matrix. The $u_{a\mu}(R)$ can be expanded as

$
u_{a\mu}(R)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m_aN}}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\,\exp(iq\cdot R)
$

where $q$ is the phonon wavevector, $m_a$ is the mass of atom $a$, $\lambda$ are branches of the dispersion relation, $\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)$ is a component of the eigenvector indexed by $q\lambda$, and $Q_\lambda(q)$ are the 'normal coordinates'. Note that including the term $\exp(iq\cdot a)$ in the expansion is tantamount to redefining the dynamical matrix.

Substituting the expansion into the potential gives

$
\begin{align}
V
&=\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{Ra\mu}\sum_{R'b\nu}\frac{\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(R,R')}{\sqrt{m_am_{b}}}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\,e^{iq\cdot R}\sum_{q'\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(q')\,Q_{\lambda'}(q')\,e^{iq'\cdot R'} \\
&=\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{Ra\mu}\sum_{R'b\nu}\frac{\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(0,R'-R)}{\sqrt{m_am_{b}}}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\,e^{iq\cdot R}\sum_{q'\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(q')\,Q_{\lambda'}(q')\,e^{iq'\cdot R'} \\
&=\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{Ra\mu}\sum_{R'b\nu}\frac{\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(0,R')}{\sqrt{m_am_{b}}}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\,e^{iq\cdot R}\sum_{q'\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(q')\,Q_{\lambda'}(q')\,e^{iq'\cdot (R'+R)} \\
&=\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{a\mu}\sum_{R'b\nu}\frac{\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(0,R')}{\sqrt{m_am_{b}}}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\sum_{q'\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(q')\,Q_{\lambda'}(q')\,e^{iq'\cdot R'}\underbrace{\left(\sum_R e^{i(q+q')\cdot R}\right)}_{N\delta_{q,-q'}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a\mu}\sum_{R'b\nu}\frac{\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(0,R')}{\sqrt{m_am_{b}}}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\sum_{\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(-q)\,Q_{\lambda'}(-q)\,e^{-iq\cdot R'} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a\mu}\sum_{b\nu}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)\,Q_\lambda(q)\sum_{\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(-q)\,Q_{\lambda'}(-q)\,\underbrace{\sum_{R'}\frac{\Phi_{a\mu,b\nu}(0,R')}{\sqrt{m_am_{b}}}e^{-iq\cdot R'}}_{D_{a\mu,b\nu}(-q)} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a\mu}\sum_{b\nu}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(-q)\,Q_\lambda(-q)\sum_{\lambda'}\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(q)\,Q_{\lambda'}(q)\,D_{a\mu,b\nu}(q) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a\mu}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(-q)\,Q_\lambda(-q)\sum_{\lambda'}Q_{\lambda'}(q)\underbrace{\sum_{b\nu}D_{a\mu,b\nu}(q)\,\varepsilon_{b\nu}^{\lambda'}(q)}_{\omega^2(q\lambda')\,\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda'}(q)} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a\mu}\sum_{q\lambda}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)^*\,Q_\lambda(q)^*\sum_{\lambda'}Q_{\lambda'}(q)\,\omega^2(q\lambda')\,\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda'}(q) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{q\lambda\lambda'}\omega^2(q\lambda')\,Q_\lambda(q)^*\,Q_{\lambda'}(q)\underbrace{\sum_{a\mu}\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda}(q)^*\varepsilon_{a\mu}^{\lambda'}(q)}_{\delta_{\lambda\lambda'}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{q\lambda}\omega^2(q\lambda)\,|Q_\lambda(q)|^2 \\
\end{align}
$